# Slow editor in Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse

Since I updated Eclipse from Ganymede to Galileo on Mac OS X 10.5, the editor is incredible slow, independently of the programming language: I tried Python and PHP, and for both, the editor scrolling is very slow, like on a very old computer (I'm using am up-to-date Macbook). Any idea where I could tweak it?

Comment: Haven't had this problem on Windows version, on several computers, so I would guess it is related to MacOs. Could someone on a Mac confirm if this is linked only to his computer, or to the Mac version ?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and got some improvement after making the following edit to eclipse.ini:

> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=**1.6**

You should find the file under Macintosh HD > Developer > Applications > eclipse > Eclipse > Contents > MacOS

You can also try bumping up the various memory parameters in the same file.

Good luck!

Comment: I bumped my permgen up from 256m to 512m. That seems to have helped a lot. I have a ton of plugins so I'm assuming that's what was killing me.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this problem on Ubuntu 9.10. Really slow scrolling i Eclipse Galileo on a new laptop (with P8700 2.53 GHz, 6 GB, ATI Radeon Mobile 4570). Had no issues with Ganymede on older Ubuntu on slower compters. No problems with e.g. FireFox, Compiz, other programs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook Pro unibody 15 inches, 2.66GHz and 4GB RAM. I have Mac OS X 10.6.2. I just upgraded my 2 year long Eclipse Ganymede to Galileo 64-bit Cocoa, and although generally better, the editor scrolling was indeed jaggier and slower, with a noticeable drag. Both versions were configured pretty much the same way and both were using the latest JRE 1.6.0.

**I switched back to Galileo 32-bit Carbon, and experience no more slowness.**

It is as smooth as my previous Ganymede version (which was in fact 32-bit Carbon). So the difference is precisely that the 64-bit Cocoa version is slower than the Carbon 32-bit one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the whole visible text is repainted each time you scroll instead of only the little area that is revealed.